# Huge db.log in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: database, log, magento2.3.3

I enabled the /var/debug/db.log with this:

```
bin/magento dev:query-log:enable
```

With two page loads in front end it generated 128025 lines. Is that normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.
For each query executed you also get the stack trace so you can easily check where that query was executed.
You can run it with `--include-call-stack=false` option to disable the stack trace.
run `bin/magento dev:query-log:enable -h` to see what other options you have available for the command.

Comment: Thanks. I found what i need